# Java Native Access - GetExtendedTcpTable: Bounds exceeds available space

Tags: java, jna

I have implemented the GetExtendedTcpTable() with JNA, but when I use the function, I receive an error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Bounds exceeds available space : size=28, offset=52
```

The definition of my function is as follows:

```
public interface IPHlpAPIExtended extends IPHlpAPI {

    IPHlpAPIExtended INSTANCE = Native.load("IPHlpAPI", IPHlpAPIExtended.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    int GetExtendedTcpTable( MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID pTcpTable, IntByReference pdwSize, boolean bOrder, int ulAf, int TableClass, int Reserved );

    @Structure.FieldOrder( { "dwNumEntries", "table" } )
    public static class MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID extends Structure {

        public WinDef.DWORD dwNumEntries;
        public MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID[] table = new MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID[]{ new MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID() };

        public MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID() {
        }

        public MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID( Pointer pointer ) {
            super( pointer );
            this.read();
        }

        @Override
        public void read() {
            super.read();
            if ( dwNumEntries.intValue() > 0 ) {
                table = ( MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID[] ) table[0].toArray( dwNumEntries.intValue() );
            } else {
                table = new MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID[]{ new MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID() };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
IPHlpAPIExtended.MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID pTcpTable = new IPHlpAPIExtended.MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID();
final IntByReference pdwSize = new IntByReference( 0 );

try {
    if ( IPHlpAPIExtended.INSTANCE.GetExtendedTcpTable( pTcpTable, pdwSize, true, AF_INET,
                    IPHlpAPIExtended.TCP_TABLE_CLASS.TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL.ordinal(), 0 ) == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER ) {

        IPHlpAPIExtended.MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID newPTcpTable = new IPHlpAPIExtended.MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID( pTcpTable.getPointer() );

        assertThat(
            IPHlpAPIExtended.INSTANCE.GetExtendedTcpTable( newPTcpTable, pdwSize, true, AF_INET,

   IPHlpAPIExtended.TCP_TABLE_CLASS.TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL.ordinal(), 0 ) ).isEqualTo( NO_ERROR );

        for ( int i = 0; i < newPTcpTable.dwNumEntries.intValue(); i++ ) {
            final IPHlpAPIExtended.MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID row = newPTcpTable.table[i];
            System.out.println( row.dwOwningPid.intValue() );
        }
    } else {
        // TODO getLasError()
        Assertions.fail( "GetExtendedTcpTable terminate with errors" );
    }
} catch ( Throwable t ) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

The dwNumEntries field is correctly populated. But the row:

```
table = ( MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID[] ) table[0].toArray( dwNumEntries.intValue() );
```

Raises the exception.

**EDIT:**

This is the mapping for MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID :

```
@Structure.FieldOrder( { "dwState", "dwLocalAddr", "dwLocalPort", "dwRemoteAddr", "dwRemotePort", "dwOwningPid" } )
public static class MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID extends Structure {

    public WinDef.DWORD dwState;
    public WinDef.DWORD dwLocalAddr;
    public WinDef.DWORD dwLocalPort;
    public WinDef.DWORD dwRemoteAddr;
    public WinDef.DWORD dwRemotePort;
    public WinDef.DWORD dwOwningPid;

}
```

**EDIT**

My solution has been changed to the signature of the function.

```
int GetExtendedTcpTable( Memory pTcpTable, IntByReference pdwSize, boolean bOrder, int ulAf, int TableClass, int Reserved );
```

Now pTcpTable it's a more generic **Memory** parameter, and the code is now the following:

```
    final IPHlpAPIExtended.MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID pTcpTable = new IPHlpAPIExtended.MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID();
    final IntByReference pdwSize = new IntByReference( 0 );

    final Memory mTcpTable = new Memory( pTcpTable.size() );
    if ( IPHlpAPIExtended.INSTANCE.GetExtendedTcpTable( mTcpTable, pdwSize, true, AF_INET,
            IPHlpAPIExtended.TCP_TABLE_CLASS.TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL.ordinal(), 0 ) == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER ) {

        final Memory newMTcpTable = new Memory( pdwSize.getValue() );
        assertThat( IPHlpAPIExtended.INSTANCE.GetExtendedTcpTable( newMTcpTable, pdwSize, true, AF_INET,
                IPHlpAPIExtended.TCP_TABLE_CLASS.TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL.ordinal(), 0 ) ).isEqualTo( NO_ERROR );

        final IPHlpAPIExtended.MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID newPTcpTable = new IPHlpAPIExtended.MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID( newMTcpTable );

        System.out.println( "Table Size: " + newPTcpTable.dwNumEntries.intValue() );
        for (int i = 0; i < newPTcpTable.dwNumEntries.intValue(); i++) {
            final IPHlpAPIExtended.MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID item = newPTcpTable.table[i];
            System.out.println( "PID: " + item.dwOwningPid.longValue());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your mapping for `MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID`?

Comment: In the edited part you can see the `MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID` mapping.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `Structure#toArray` in a way it was not designed.  It's intended to work on memory already alloated for the full size of the array (or not allocated at all, in which case it allocates). 
 But you are using it in a case where, in your mapping of the `MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID` structure, you have defined the second element as an array, with a fixed size of 1, and thus allocated memory for it.

```
public MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID[] table = new MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID[]{ new MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID() };
```

This isn't wrong in itself, and you have to declare something there, although there's no need to initialize the element with a Java object.  Just assign `new MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID[1]`.

JNA allocates memory for the size of a structure immediately on assignment, so the result of the way you assigned it is that the `table` element already is mapped to native memory with a size of exactly 28 (4 bytes for the `DWORD` and 4*6 bytes for the single `MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID` element.)

This initial allocation of the single element to `table` works fine, but when you attempt to reassign that variable using `Structure#toArray` it fails the memory bounds check because the smaller memory has been allocated, and `toArray()` checks if memory has been allocated before creating new memory.

It may be possible to reassign the variable defining your own array in plain Java, without using Jna's `Structure#toArray()` and its bounds checks.  This code should work in some circumstances if the native side allocates the memory; however, if you are required to allocate memory yourself, it won't work.

```
@Override
public void read() {
    readField("dwNumEntries");
    table = new MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID[dwNumEntries.intValue()];
    super.read();
}
```

Another approach is to not bother redefining the array (`table`) but instead map `table` as a `Pointer` or a `StructureByReference` (a more strongly typed pointer).  Then instead of the `read()` override, you would access the native memory pointed to, and create the array on the fly.  You could use a getter function like:

```
public MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID[] getTable() {
    Pointer[] array = table.getPointerArray(0, dwNumEntries.intValue());
    MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID[] rows = new MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID[array.length];
    for (int i=0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rows[i] = new MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID(array[i]);
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Finally as you have discovered, if you allocate the memory yourself using a `Memory` object, and return that, you can then pass the pre-allocated memory to the constructor and your code should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In fact, initializing the array may not make much sense. I tried the first solution, but it doesn't work, I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. But your sentence: "JNA allocates memory for the size of a structure immediately on assignmen..." was inspiring to me. I changed my strategy, see the new edit.